# CakePHP select field does not populate

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm Using `cakePHP 2.3.8`

I have two tables: application, computer_application. The relationship is one `application` hasMany `computer_application`, foreign key is `application_id`

in my ComputerApplication **model**:

```
class ComputerApplication extends AppModel{
        public $name = "ComputerApplication";
        public $useTable = "computer_application";

        var $belongsTo = array(
            'Computer' => array(
                'className'     => 'Computer',
                'foreignKey'    => 'computer_id',
                'dependent'     => true
            ),
            'Application' => array(
                'className'     => 'Application',
                'foreignKey'    => 'application_id',
                'dependent'     => true
            )
        );
    }
```

In my ComputerApplication **controller**. **HERE I INITIALIZE THE POPULATION OF DROPDOWN** in `**add**` function

```
    public function add($id=null) {
                if (!$id) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
                }

                $this->set('computerApplications',
                    $this->ComputerApplication->Application->find('list',
                    array('fields' => array('description') ) ) );
}
```

Now In my `Add` **View**

```
echo $this->Form->create("computerApplication");
echo $this->Form->input('application_id',array('empty'=>''));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
```

My problem is that it won't populate the select input. This is the first time I used 2 words in table [`computer_application`] using cake since I don't have problem populating other table with just one word. Just help me identify which I need to tweak for it to populate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->set('applications', ...
```

and not

```
$this->set('computerApplications', ...
```